# Issue with bash mv command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I am trying two write a .sh script that fetches gtk themes from github to /tmp/ and then moves them into another folder to sort out icons from themes and so on.

My problem ist after downloading the files, when I mv them, the output should be multiple folders like ( Kali-Dark Kali-Light ) and the folder should contain ( gtk-2.0 gtk-3.0 ) but my actual output is ( gtk-2.0 gtk-3.0 Kali-Light).

So for some weird reason it moves the inner of Kali-Dark to the folder but Kali-Light is moved as wanted as a folder.

My Shell script looks like

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git clone https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-themes /tmp/MyLinux/download/Kali-Theme
mkdir /tmp/MyLinux/sort

mv /tmp/MyLinux/download/Kali-Theme/share/themes/Kali-Dark /tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/
mv /tmp/MyLinux/download/Kali-Theme/share/themes/Kali-Light /tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/
```

And the output of ls is

```
gnome-shell
gtk-2.0
gtk-3.0
gtk-4.0
index.theme
Kali-Light
```

What it should look like

```
Kali-Dark
Kali-Light
```

Comment: i would expect `mkdir` to have additional `-p` flag

Comment: this `mv /tmp/MyLinux/download/Kali-Theme/share/themes/Kali-Dark /tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/Kali-Dark` and
`mv /tmp/MyLinux/download/Kali-Theme/share/themes/Kali-Light /tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/Kali-Light` is how the move cmds should look like

Comment: @Verthais Umm, no. If it happens that `/tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/Kali-Dark` already exists, then you will be creating `/tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/Kali-Dark/Kali-Dark`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make a directory named `themes`, so your first `mv` command is renaming `Kali-Dark`, then the second command is putting `Kali-Light` inside of the renamed directory.

Change `mkdir /tmp/MyLinux/sort` to `mkdir -p /tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes` and this will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you only create the folder 'sort':

```
mkdir /tmp/MyLinux/sort
```

and then you tell `mv` to move the *Kali-Dark* directory into `/tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes/` so `mv` *thinks* you are mentioning a 'themes' target directory which doesn't yet exist, so you want to use 'themes' as a destination directory instead of the source directory name ('Kali-Dark'), so it creates the 'themes' directory and then the **contents** of `Kali-Dark/*` will be put inside `themes/`. Now the next `mv` command will see that the 'themes' target-directory exists (as it was just created), so it will use the source directory name *Kali-Light* under the target `themes/` directory. And you will have the result you mentioned.

What you want to do is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TARGET_PATH="/tmp/MyLinux"
mkdir -p $TARGET_PATH/{download,sort/themes}

git clone https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-themes $TARGET_PATH/download

mv $TARGET_PATH/download/share/themes/Kali-Dark $TARGET_PATH/sort/themes/
mv $TARGET_PATH/download/share/themes/Kali-Light $TARGET_PATH/sort/themes/
```

Now `mv` will *think* you want the source directory names included under the destination path (which now exists) and you will get:

```
$ ls /tmp/MyLinux/sort/themes
Kali-Dark
Kali-Light
```

Hints:

- create the full destination paths beforehand
- make use of the ***v**erbose* option `mv -v ...` to see what it is actually doing (makes it easier to debug your script)